# How to initialize multi-dimensional array with different default value

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, default-value

I am trying to initialize 2-dimensional array of integer values with -1. When I create a new array, it is automatically filled with 0. 
I know I can do it with 2 for cycles, but I imagine there should be some way of doing this while the array is being build (so I don't have to go through it two times), so that instead of 0, provided value would be inserted. Is it possible? 
If not during the initial building of the array, is there some other time or code saving way, or am I stuck with 2 for cycles?

Comment: How large are these arrays?

Comment: Array size is based on the input of the function that creates it, I forgot to mention that. Direct initialization is out of question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a multidimensional array, the loops are most likely the best approach, unless the array is small enough to initialize directly in code.

If you're using a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), you could initialize the first sub-array, then use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) to copy these values into each other sub-array.  This will still require one iteration through the first sub array, and one loop through N-1 outer arrays, but the copy operation will be faster than the loops.

Comment: I'm indeed using multidimensional array. Well, I guess I will have to go the 'oldschool' way then.

Answer (score 22):

Try something like this: `int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { -1 }, { -1 }, { -1 }, { -1} };`

or with dimension `int[,] array2D = new int[4,2] { { -1,-1 }, { -1,-1 }, { -1,-1 }, {-1,-1} };`

Comment: Not sure why the -1 - This is perfectly valid for small 2D arrays, and the best option in that case.  +1 from me...  (This stops being maintainable pretty quickly if the arrays are large, though)

Comment: Same from me, I forgot the mention the important detail in the original question.

Comment: That's fine, @ReedCopsey answered your question well, I guess

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this kind of 2D array initialization is wrong:

```py
mat = [[0] * 5] * 5  # wrong
mat = [[0] * 5] for _ in range(5)]  # correct
```

because you are copying the reference of the inner array multiple times, and changing one of them will eventually change all.

```py
mat[0][0] = 1
print(mat)
# 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0
```

In C#, we have the similar issue.

```
var mat = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5).ToArray(), 5).ToArray();
```

Since array is a reference type, the outside Repeat() are actually copying the reference of the inner array.

Then if you do have the need to create and initialize multidimensional arrays without using for loops, then maybe a custom helper class will help:

```
static class HelperFunctions
{
    public static T[][] Repeat<T>(this T[] arr, int count)
    {
        var res = new T[count][];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //arr.CopyTo(res[i], 0);
            res[i] = (T[])arr.Clone();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use it:

```
using static HelperFunctions;

var mat = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5).ToArray().Repeat(5);
```

This will do.